# Why would you say "it changed me" instead of "it changed myself" here?

Tags: meaning

I was correcting a sentence written by a Japanese friend, and I corrected one of his sentences to:

> "Learning foreign languages changed me".

He asked me why he could not use "myself" instead. I am kind of at a loss of how to explain this to him. Please help me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Related: [Why is “herself” required in this particular sentence?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/189095/why-is-herself-required-in-this-particular-sentence)

Comment: It would have made greater sense to have migrated this question five days ago not now.

Answer (score 55):

> **myself** *pronoun*
>   1 (reflexive first person singular) Used by a speaker to refer to himself or herself as the object of a verb or preposition when he or she is the subject of the clause.
>   ‘I strolled around, muttering to myself’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/myself)

The reason it sounds odd is because in your quote, the subject is "Learning foreign languages", not the first-person individual. Had the sentence been "By learning foreign languages, I changed myself", the word '*myself*' wouldn't have sounded out of place.

Comment: Ah, but there's more to it than this! (see my answer footling at the bottom of the page!)

Answer (score 40):

"Myself" is a reflexive pronoun, which can only be used when the subject and object of the verb are the same.

***He*** patted **me** on the back.

but

***I*** patted **myself** on the back.

In this case the subject is "learning foreign languages", but the object is your friend. The sentence could be reworked to use "myself": "By learning foreign languages, I have changed myself." (The result doesn't have quite the same meaning as the original sentence, though.)

Other reflexive pronouns include "itself", "themselves", "himself", etc.

Comment: `Other reflexive pronouns include`... basically anything in the form *someone*self.

Comment: In *I gave Suzy a picture of herself*  herself is not an object and Suzy is not a subject. And *myself* is not an object in *I did it by myself*.

Comment: I'm sorry but this is one of those lemmings' questions. [,,,]"which can only be used when the subject and object of the verb are the same": He patted me on the back. Great; but not: he patted myself on the back.  Your first statement implies that it would be. The OP's question does not contain the word friend.

Answer (score 17):

Normally with 'myself' I would be the subject.
I pinched myself.
But: he pinched me.

Answer (score 12):

The Original Poster's Japanese friend has a very good reason to ask this question, and if we don't understand what this is, then we cannot fully answer the question.

We usually need a reflexive pronoun when two noun phrases in a clause refer to the same being or entity:

- Bob<sub>(i)</sub> kicked himself<sub>(i)</sub>

These don't need to be the subject and object of the clause:

- Bob<sub>(i)</sub> had a picture of himself<sub>(i)</sub>.
- I gave Bob<sub>(i)</sub> a picture of himself<sub>(i)</sub>.

In the first example above the reflexive *himself* is the complement of a preposition. In the second, the original referring expression, *Bob*, is an object, not a subject.

Now, we also need to use a reflexive if a pronouns co-refers with the UNEXPRESSED SUBJECT of a clause. For example, consider the following:

- Take a look at **yourself** in the mirror. You look great!

Here the unexpressed subject of the imperative clause is *you*. Because the pronoun after the word *at* refers to the same person as the person who's going to be doing the looking, *you*, it must be reflexive. A reflexive pronoun is also required in the following example:

- By teaching yourself English, you can massively improve your employment prospects.

Here the understood subject of the verb *teaching* is *you*. We can rephrase the sentence, rather awkwardly, like this:

- By your teaching yourself English, you can massively improve your employment prospects.

So the person being taught is the same as the person doing the teaching. Because *yourself* is in the same clause as the unexpressed subject, it needs to be reflexive.

Now let's have a look at the Original Poster's sentence:

- Learning foreign languages changed me.

Here the unexpressed subject of the verb *learning* is me. The object of the verb *change* is also me.  So the question is why isn't the object of the verb *changed* required to be reflexive here, given that it occurs in the same clause as the verb *learning*—which has a co-referential, though unexpressed, subject?

One extremely bad answer would be to say that the subject of the verb *changed* is not the same as the object of the verb *learning*. This is a bad answer, because as we have seen from the *Bob had a picture of himself* example, if a pronoun refers to the same entity as a noun phrase in the same clause, it is usually required to be reflexive *regardless of whether either of them is the subject or the object*. In the photo example, *himself* is not what is being given.

The real answer to the Original Poster's question is that we only need a reflexive pronoun if it occurs *in the same **minimal** clause* as a co-referential noun phrase. In other words they must both occur in the same smallest clause. In the following example *he* occurs in a smaller clause inside the larger sentence and the noun *Bob* is not inside this same small clause. For this reason no reflexive is required:

- Bob believes [**he** is a great singer].

Similarly, in the example given by the Original Poster, the unexpressed subject of the verb *learning* is in a smaller clause inside the larger sentence. The pronoun *me* does not occur inside this clause and isn't required to be reflexive:

- [ **<s>Me</s>** learning foreign languages] changed **me**.